How to use an http browser to upload files from local IPFS gateway?
So I am trying to create a decentralized NFT market where users get to upload and retrieve content from IPFS. I am using the  api to connect my frontend (react app) with my local ipfs gateway.
So this is my configuration setup for the connection between the  api with react app:
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';

const client = create(
  {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5001,
    protocol: 'http',
  }
);

Add this is how I am trying to upload the submitted file to my local ipfs node:
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (!file) {
        console.error("No file selected");
        return;
    }

    setLoading(true);

    try {
        const result = await client.add(file);
        const url = `http://localhost:8080/ipfs/${result.path}`;
        setCid(url);
        console.log("File uploaded successfully:", url);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error uploading file:", error.message);
    } finally {
        setLoading(false);
    }
};

Lastly I get this error when I try to upload the files:
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5001/api/v0/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

AND
App.jsx:43 
        
        POST http://localhost:5001/webui/add?stream-channels=true&progress=false net::ERR_FAILED 302 (Found)


This question is similar to: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I kind of find it hard to relate my problem with you reference as my problem deals with a connection between a react app with a local IPFS gateway? Is there something that I am failing to see? cause from where I am standing there is literally no need for a backend service only API communication

The message means http://localhost:5001/ needs to be setting CORS headers on its responses that permit http://localhost:5173/ access to it. Your const client = create( is your backend.
